# How to prevent image from distorting when Flash is Zoomed

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am loading a jpg into my Flash. When I zoom into the flash in the browser (for example, setting the zoom to 125%) the jpg in the flash starts to distort and pixelate. How do I get Flash to not pixelate the jpg?

Comment: Can you show an example of the distortion (pic please)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the smoothing on your loaded jpg to true.

Something like:

```
_urlRequest=new URLRequest("urltoimage");
_loader=new Loader;
_loader.load(_urlRequest);
_loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:IOErrorEvent):void{ trace("ERROR: "+e) });
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ImageLoaded, false, 0, true);



function ImageLoaded(e:Event):void {

    _loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ImageLoaded); 

    Bitmap(_loader.content).smoothing = true;

    addChild(_loader);

}
```

Comment: That's done it. I wonder why that is not in the manual somewhere?

Comment: It is: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html?#smoothing